# ¿Como agregar varios parametros a la url con el conector correcto? con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Cómo puedo hacer para agregar varios parametros a la url y que se coloque el signo de `?` en caso de que sea el primero o `&` en caso de que quiera agregar otro.

yo no coloque enlaces `<a>`, quise hacer la redirecion con javascript pero ahora no sé cómo hacer para que se agregue el conector correcto.

he visto en algunas paginas y todos los hacen con el href de `<a>` pero si pudieran ayudarme de esta forma me quedaria mejor.

```
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr> 
              <th class="toggleCelda1" href="hola" >Nombre de Producto<i class="fas fa-sort" id="uno"></i></th>
              <th class="toggleCelda2">Precio unitario<i class="fas fa-sort" id="uno" ></i></th>
              <th class="toggleCelda3">Cantidad<i class="fas fa-sort" id="uno" ></i></th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Refresco de Limón</td>
            <td> $12 </td>
            <td> 2 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Refresco de Toronja</td>
            <td> $11 </td>
            <td> 3 </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

Javascrip

    let toggleCelda1 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda1');
    let toggleCelda2 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda2');
    let toggleCelda3 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda3');
    let toggleIconCelda1 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda1 i')
    let toggleIconCelda2 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda2 i')
    let toggleIconCelda3 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda3 i')
   
    
    
    var valoresparametros = []
    
    
    const valores = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(valores);
    var values = urlParams.values()

    console.log(valores)
    console.log(valoresparametros)
    
    
    for (const value of values) {
        valoresparametros.push(value)
    }

    
    
    // VALIDO SI EL ARRAY CONTIENTE LOS PARAMETROS Y DEPENDIENDO SI ES POSITIVO O NEGATIVO MUESTRO EL ICONO
    
    function cambiarIconos (IconCelda, orientacion) {
        IconCelda.setAttribute('class', 'iconshow fas fa-sort-' + orientacion)
    }
    
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        if (valoresparametros.includes('t1')) {
            cambiarIconos(toggleIconCelda1, 'down')
        } else if (valoresparametros.includes('-t1')) {
            cambiarIconos(toggleIconCelda1, 'up')
        }
        if (valoresparametros.includes('t2')) {
            cambiarIconos(toggleIconCelda2, 'down')
        } else if (valoresparametros.includes('-t2')) {
            cambiarIconos(toggleIconCelda2, 'up')
        }
        if (valoresparametros.includes('t3')) {
            cambiarIconos(toggleIconCelda3, 'down')
        } else if (valoresparametros.includes('-t3')) {
            cambiarIconos(toggleIconCelda3, 'up')
        }
        if (valoresparametros.includes('t4')) {
            cambiarIconos(toggleIconCelda4, 'down')
        } else if (valoresparametros.includes('-t4')) {
            cambiarIconos(toggleIconCelda4, 'up')
        }
        
    })


     
    function mostrarIcono (IconCelda, OrderType) {


         
        if (IconCelda.classList.contains('fa-sort')) {

            IconCelda.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-sort-down')
            IconCelda.classList.add('iconshow')
            location.href = window.location + '?ordering=t' + OrderType

        } else if (IconCelda.classList.contains('fa-sort-down')) {

            IconCelda.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-sort-up')
            IconCelda.classList.add('iconshow')
            
            if (window.location.search.includes('=t' + OrderType)) {

                let cambio = window.location.search.replace('=t' + OrderType, '=-t' + OrderType)
                location.href = cambio

            } else {

                location.href = '?ordering=-t' + OrderType 
            }

        } else {

            IconCelda.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-sort')

            if (window.location.search.includes('?ordering=-t' + OrderType)) {

                let otro = window.location.search.replace('?ordering=-t' + OrderType , ' ')
                location.href = otro
            }
            if (valoresparametros.length == 1) {
                location.href = '/'
            }

        }

    };



    toggleCelda1.addEventListener('click', function () {
        mostrarIcono(toggleIconCelda1, 1)
    })

    toggleCelda2.addEventListener('click', function () {
        mostrarIcono(toggleIconCelda2, 2)
    })

    toggleCelda3.addEventListener('click', function () {
        mostrarIcono(toggleIconCelda3, 3)
    })
```

Comment: Sin añadir basura a la pregunta siempre será mejor

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer. Entiendo el inconveniente de tener que discriminar cuando corresponse `?` vs `&`, pero sin saber el caso de uso, no puedo sugerir algo mejor. Se supone que tienes botones que cambian el criterio para ordenar una lista? Y al pincharlos te manda a otra URL que contiene los criterios nuevos?

Answer (score 0):

Arma una única variable que contenga todos los parámetros que le vas a añadir a la URL.

`let something = '';`

Luego, cada vez que le vayas a añadir un nuevo parámetro, validas si está vacía y, si lo está, pones `?algo=algunacosa`; si no lo está, pones `&otraCosa=algoMas`

`something += (something.length == 0) ? '?' + algunacosa : '&' + otracosa;`